# Replace a particular word with another one in a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

How can I find a particular word in text file and replace that word with another one and write back the test to file(If text is paragraph separated).I can do replace word; if its not paragraph separated .using string.find and string replace.

Comment: Read the file into some sort of container (I would suggest `std::vector<std::string>` ) and then look through that.

Comment: Define what it means to be paragraph separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are comfortable with replacing words in a single paragraph and that you are doubtful regarding text with multiple paragraphs.

Please look into a function called "getline()" function.

This function reads entire your text until it encounters a "\n" element (Next line)

So you can use this getline function to get one whole paragraph into a string.

Using this getline function in a while loop allows you to get all the paragraphs from the text file

An example code has been provided below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a,b;
    a="he";
    b="she";
    fstream text("text.txt");
    string line;
    while (!text.eof( ))
    {
        getline(text,line);
        cout<<line<<endl;
        //This string "line" is basically a string containing your first paragraph
        //ADD your find and replace code here for the string "line".
        //The second time the while loop executes the string "line" will contain the second paragraph and so on..
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the search word is at beginning of a next paragraph.my code doesn't detect the word .This is my code.                                                                         while (!(fid.eof()))
   {

    getline(fid, data,' ');
    if (searchKey.compare(data) == 0)
    {
     count=count + 1;
    }

Comment: The paragraphs ends with a "\n" right.

Comment: a paragraph ends with '\n' which is next line escape sequence.So when u read the file u get the two paragraphs merged connected with a \n .U can visualize it as paragraph1\nparagraph2. this means that the getline function includes the \ncharacter with word at the starting of paragraph 2.If u start ur second paragraph with a space u will get the proper count

Comment: U will also encounter the same problem with last word of the first paragraph.

Comment: i already tried that one.Thak you....

Comment: You are Welcome